# Performance call scalar-function in MERGE statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, function

I have code with a `MERGE` statement calling to a scalar function, and I get very poor performance.

This code could take me 30 minutes and more, and sometimes it can fail in the middle.

My code:

```
MERGE INTO Table1 AS md
USING (SELECT * FROM Table2 edb
       WHERE edb.FileId = @FileId
         AND edb.IsRowError = 0) edbTable ON dbo.GetId(edbTable.Filed1, edbTable.Filed2, edbTable.Filed3, edbTable.Filed4, edbTable.Filed5, edbTable.Filed6) = md.Id
                                          AND md.IsActive = 1

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
        SET .
         .
         .
```

The function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetId] 
    (@Filed1 NVARCHAR(9),
     @Filed2 NVARCHAR(9),
     @Filed3 NVARCHAR(13),
     @Filed4 INT,
     @Filed5 DATE,
     @Filed6 INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Id INT = NULL

    IF ((@Filed5 IS NULL) OR (@Filed6 = 0))
    BEGIN
        SET @Id = (SELECT TOP 1 md.Id 
                   FROM Table1 md with(NOLOCK)
                   JOIN Table3 mb with(NOLOCK) ON md.Table3Id = mb.Id
                   WHERE (mb.Filed1 = @Filed1 AND mb.Filed2 = @Filed2 
                          OR mb.Filed1 = @Filed2 AND mb.Filed2 = @Filed1)
                     AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                     AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                     AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                   ORDER BY md.LastUpdateDate DESC)

        IF @Id IS NOT NULL
             RETURN @Id 
     ELSE 
         SET @Id = (SELECT TOP 1 md.Id 
                    FROM Table1 md with(NOLOCK)
                    JOIN Table3 mb with(NOLOCK) ON md.Table3Id = mb.Id
                    WHERE (mb.Filed1 = @Filed1 OR mb.Filed1 = @Filed1)
                      AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                      AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                      AND Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                      AND @Filed1 > 0
                    ORDER BY  md.LastUpdateDate DESC)

         IF @Id IS NOT NULL
             RETURN @Id 
         ELSE 
             set @Id =(select top 1 md.Id from Table1 md with(NOLOCK)
                                            join Table3 mb with(NOLOCK) on md.Table3Id = mb.Id
                                            where (mb.Filed1 = @Filed2 
                                                or mb.Filed2 = @Filed2 )
                                              and mb.Filed7 = 1
                                              and @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                                              and @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                                              and @Filed2 >0
                                            order by md.LastUpdateDate desc)
 end
 else
 begin
   set @Id = (select top 1 md.Id from Table1 md with(NOLOCK)
                                            join Table3 mb with(NOLOCK) on md.Table3Id = mb.Id
                                            where (mb.Filed1 = @Filed1 and mb.Filed2 = @Filed2 
                                               or mb.Filed1 = @Filed2 and mb.Filed2 = @Filed1 )
                                              and mb.Filed7 = 1
                                              and @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                                              and @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                                              and (@Filed5 = md.ContractDate or (@Filed5 is null and md.ContractDate is null))
                                              and @Filed6 = md.PurchasePrice)
   if @Id is not NULL
      RETURN @Id 
   else
      set @Id =(select top 1 md.Id from Table1 md with(NOLOCK)
                                            join Table3 mb with(NOLOCK) on md.Table3Id = mb.Id
                                            where (mb.Filed1 = @Filed1 
                                                or mb.Filed2 = @Filed1 )
                                              and mb.Filed7 = 1
                                              and @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                                              and @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                                              and (@Filed5 = md.ContractDate or (@Filed5 is null and md.ContractDate is null))
                                              and @Filed6  = md.PurchasePrice
                                              and @Filed1 >0)
   if @Id is not NULL
      RETURN @Id 
   else
      set @Id =(select top 1 md.Id from Table1 md with(NOLOCK)
                                            join Table3 mb with(NOLOCK) on md.Table3Id = mb.Id
                                            where (mb.Filed1 = @Filed2 
                                                or mb.Filed2 = @Filed2 )
                                              and mb.Filed7 = 1
                                              and @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                                              and @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                                              and (@Filed5 = md.ContractDate or (@Filed5 is null and md.ContractDate is null))
                                              and @Filed6 = md.PurchasePrice
                                              and @Filed2 >0)
   if @Id is not NULL
      RETURN @Id 
  end


    RETURN @Id 

END
```

What am I need to change?
How can I change the code?

I need all the `If` statmence, becouse there is a preference for which record to retrieve,  I can not convert it to `join`.
Because if some `join`, they'll give me a positive answer so it will give me a list of everyone who came out of the population, and it's important to know whether it's because of the first or second or third join, because I have priorities to choose.

If I do this instead of `if` to `join`, is there a way to pull out the first line that goes out? That is to say: if I do join and the first has no results and the second one has, and in the third, that will return only the result of the second and not the third - is there such a thing?

Comment: Scalar functions are known to perform poorly (although they are much better in SQL server 2019 if you make use of the inlining for scalar functions). I would suggest changing to an inline table-value function. The function above, as well, will have to scan/seek on the tables `Table1` and `Table3` up to 6 times; if you can change that to a single statement I would. A `CASE` expression would seem the best option. Also, why are you using `WITH (NOLOCK)` in every single reference to a table?

Comment: @Larnu - I know it after that I search in google... But what can I change?? and How to change? I have `Sql server 2014`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is an exact replication of your logic, but as an inline table-value function. This could, very likely, be trimmed down further where requisites are the same. For example `mb.File7 = 1 AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4` appears in *every* `WHEN` clause, so that should be moved from all of the `WHEN` clauses and put in the `WHERE`. That would likely make the query more performant and also far easier to read.

Anyway, this does the same logic. I've added a couple of comments in the code though which you may want to look at:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetID (@Filed1 nvarchar(9), --Honestly, give these better names. These parameters don't tell you anything about what they are
                                               --which'll make it harder for people who don't know your function to use it.
                          @Filed2 nvarchar(9),
                          @Filed3 nvarchar(13),
                          @Filed4 int,
                          @Filed5 date,
                          @Filed6 int)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN

    SELECT TOP 1 --This may be a bad idea, we'll see
           CASE WHEN @Filed5 IS NULL OR @Filed6 = 0 THEN CASE WHEN (mb.Filed1 = @Filed1 AND mb.Filed2 = @Filed2 
                                                                OR  mb.Filed1 = @Filed2 AND mb.Filed2 = @Filed1)
                                                               AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                                                               AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                                                               AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4 THEN md.Id
                                                              WHEN mb.Filed1 = @Filed1
                                                               AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                                                               AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                                                               AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                                                               AND @Filed1 > 0 THEN md.ID
                                                              WHEN @filed2 IN (mb.Filed1, mb.Filed2)
                                                               AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                                                               AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                                                               AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                                                               AND @Filed2 >0 THEN md.ID
                                                         END
                     --None of these in your original had an ORDER BY clause, was this intentional?
                     --If so, I assume you want a random row, instead. So you'll need a further
                     --CASE expression in your ORDER BY for these, and then the return either NEWID or md.LastUpdateDate
                ELSE CASE WHEN (mb.Filed1 = @Filed1   --Your parenthesis seem wrong here
                           AND  mb.Filed2 = @Filed2   --YOu have an OR in the middle
                            OR  mb.Filed1 = @Filed2   --So I doubt this does what you want
                           AND  mb.Filed2 = @Filed1 ) --But I haven't correct, as I don't know what it should do
                           AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                           AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                           AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                           AND (@Filed5 = md.ContractDate
                            OR  (@Filed5 IS NULL AND md.ContractDate IS))
                           AND @Filed6 = md.PurchasePrice THEN md.ID
                          WHEN (mb.Filed1 = @Filed1 
                            OR  mb.Filed2 = @Filed1)
                           AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                           AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                           AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                           AND (@Filed5 = md.ContractDate
                            OR (@Filed5 IS NULL AND md.ContractDate IS NULL))
                           AND @Filed6  = md.PurchasePrice
                           AND @Filed1 >0 THEN md.Id
                          WHEN (mb.Filed1 = @Filed2 
                            OR  mb.Filed2 = @Filed2)
                           AND mb.Filed7 = 1
                           AND @Filed3 = md.Filed3 
                           AND @Filed4 = md.Filed4 
                           AND (@Filed5 = md.ContractDate
                            OR  (@Filed5 IS NULL AND md.ContractDate IS NULL))
                           AND @Filed6 = md.PurchasePrice
                           AND @Filed2 >0 THEN md.Id
                     END
           END AS Id                         
    FROM dbo.Table1 md --Why md when the table is called "Table1". I assume this is anonymised
         JOIN dbo.Table3 md ON md.Table3Id = mb.Id
    ORDER BY md.LastUpdateDate DESC;
GO
```

Comment: OK, and How I need to call to this function? What am I need to change?

Comment: Like any other table value function, @Ayal, using `CROSS APPLY`.

Comment: Why would you say that @Ayal? Are you under the belief that `JOIN` is a slow process too then? You had 6 of those in your prior logic and mine has 1, so by that logic it will be vastly faster. A `JOIN` has many factors on how fast it is, size of tables, indexing, IO, etc etc. Rather than making baseless statements, why not test the above?